# Passing a javascript array to a php page using post method

Tags: javascript, ajax, arrays

I want to pass a javascript array to a php page using ajax POST request .How to achieve this.please help..Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Have a look into JSON encoding.

In PHP you can decode it using json_decode, not quite sure how you'll encode it in Javascript but it is possible

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSON

Answer (score 0):

using jQuery

```
 $.post("test.php", { 'choices[]': ["Jon", "Susan"] });
```

**Edit**

if you are creating ajax object and using it then I'll suggest to convert your data in query string send it through ajax object.

like :

```
var  userdetails = [1,2,3,4];
var queryString = "";
for(i=0; i<userdetails.length; i++){
queryString = queryString + 'userdetails[]='+userdetails[i]+'&';
}

connect.send(queryString)
```

Comment: hi narendra sisodiya...I have an array userdetails ..and pass it to php ...and I want a javascript solution not AJAX...here is what i tried ..                     connect is my XML Http object ...connect.send(userdetails);where userdetails is my array\

Answer (score 0):

example posting with json

```
var array = [1,2,3,4,5,6];
$.ajax({
  url: "mydomain.com/url",
  type: "POST",
  dataType: "json",
  data: {arrayName: array},
  complete: function() {
    //called when complete
  },
  success: function() {
    //called when successful
  },
  error: function() {
    //called when there is an error
  },
});
```

Then the json could be parsed server side.

arrays can also be sent using application/x-www-form-urlencoded - this is the default format for submitting.